# Audit Table from Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a datagridview bound to a datasource programmed to use the update function for all database access. So if i click the submit button, it will simply call the update function, check to see if there are any new rows, deleted rows, or edited rows and called the related sql command.

My Question is, is there a way to figure out which cell was edited for purpose of creating an audit table? I could then use this information to get the column that was changed and create a table.

Comment: I am not an expert on these, but where I work the database is set up with things called triggers that fire off when something is updated/deleted and inputs the data into an audit table. You may wish to look up these if you want the database level to handle it.

Comment: Ya, this is the solution i am currently looking into. But i wasnt sure if the dataset had some sort of way to differentiate edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a event to handle this such as

```
DataGridView.CellValueChanged
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`DataRow.RowState Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the DataTable like below

```
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables["mytable"].Rows)
{
  if(dr.RowState == "Modified")
   {
       //Do whatever you want to do Here   
   }
}
```

Comment: this only problem with this is that i would still need to find the changed column. I guess if i combined this with Rob's answer, i could pinpoint the changed value